# Reading objects from file and getting error

Tags: c++, file

(This is a homework project.) I am trying to write objects from class A (Contains couple of strings and ints, also a list from objects from class B ) into file. Then I have to read back these objects from the file and display their content. I am using this code:

Writing:

```
ofstream ofs("filestorage.bin", ios::app|ios::binary);
A d;
ofs.write((char *)&d, sizeof(d));
ofs.close();
```

Reading:

```
ifstream ifs("filestorage.bin", ios::binary);
A e(1);

while(ifs.read((char *)&e, sizeof(e))) {    
    cout<<e;
}

ifs.close();
```

`<<` is already redefined.

It writes the data into the file, then reads it back, displays everything I want but in the end I'm getting a nice fat "Access Violation " Error. I also tried to write and read simple variables into the file (like `int`s). That works fine; but when I try to read an object or string I get "Access Violation". The writing seams to be OK because I get no errors.

Can you tell me why this is happening and how  can I fix it? If it is necessary I can post my A and B classes too. Thanks!

Comment: There's so many things that could go wrong with this... Read/search about serialization in C++, you'll find lots of interesting stuff. As for your question, the definition of A could let someone tell you why this doesn't work.

Comment: Got to check for the eof() otherwise you'll read past the end of the file

Comment: When you get the access violation, what does the callstack say?  That may lead you directly to the problem.

Comment: You have `operator <<` defined already. Use it to write to the file like you did to `cout` and define `operator >>`.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the two operators `<<` and `>>` for your class.

```
class A {
    int a;
    string s;
pubilc:
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, A& a ) {
        out << a.a << endl;
        out << a.s << endl;
    }
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& is, A& a ) {
        //check that the stream is valid and handle appropriately.
        is >> a.a; 
        is >> a.s;
    }
};
```

**Write:**

```
A b;
ofstream ofs("filestorage.bin", ios::app|ios::binary);
ofs << b;
```

**Read:**

```
fstream ifs("filestorage.bin", ios::binary);
A b;
ifs >> b;
```

Comment: @user1803967 This would be easier if you did post your classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try just checking the stream status

```
while(ifs.read((char *)&e, sizeof(e)).good()){
     cout<<e;
}
```

Comment: You have to serialization the data. See Mat's comment.

Comment: No doubt it is not the greatest way to go, but he reports that it reads the object fine, prints, and crashes afterward - this might be "good enough", especially if A doesn't have any pointer members. And even for your solution, if you read in a loop - still have to check for eof.